# Does it make sense to retry on SSL handshake errors?

Tags: java, scala, ssl, akka-http

I`m working on client library for a REST service which talks to server via HTTPS protocol.
Recently one of the customers start seeing following errors:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doUnwrap(TLSActor.scala:368)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doInbound(TLSActor.scala:291)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(TLSActor.scala:226)
    at akka.stream.impl.Pump$class.pump(Transfer.scala:200)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.pump(TLSActor.scala:49)
    at akka.stream.impl.BatchingInputBuffer.enqueueInputElement(ActorProcessor.scala:92)
    at akka.stream.impl.BatchingInputBuffer$$anonfun$upstreamRunning$1.applyOrElse(ActorProcessor.scala:143)
```

One interesting concern here is that only 0.01% of requests failing with this error and only for single customer.
Other customers generating similar or even higher load never experienced SSL errors.

I thought that SSL handshake errors are mostly server issue with HTTPS certificate or its infrastructure.

As experiment we added retries for SSLException, similarly as we have retries for exceptions caused by 500/503 HTTP errors.
Using this version of the client all requests went through. We can clearly see in the logs that there were same amount of SSLException but on retry requests were successful.

Searching on Internet shows that some http libraries do retry on SSL errors others don`t.

So my questions:

- Does it make sense to add SSLException to the list of retirable exceptions in my client library?
- Why http libraries (in my case akka-http) do not automatically retry on such exceptions as they all have retries for TCP errors?

Comment: As long as one doesn't know exactly how it initially failed, the answer (it does or doesn't make sense to retry) doesn't matter. If many libs implicitly perform a retry, then chances are there are known problems that justify retrying. IMO, it should be OK to retry as long as the second attempt doesn't skip SSL-related validations.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think actually many http client libraries have default retries akka-http does it for tcp errors, apache http client as well, i.e. default retries in apache retries SSLExceptions as well - https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/1e5fe0e01c3b0d7f61c99462538d4b2fdcdef512/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.java

Comment: Actually i think i found answer to my questions, i was worried that adding retries for SSL issue can mask real problem on server side, but it looks quite common to retry on SSLException.

Comment: @llirik: From what I know the commonly used libraries urllib2, urllib3 and requests in Python do no retries and Mojolicious and LWP in Perl also don't.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what about https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1112 looks like it was merged.

Comment: @llirik: you are right. Thanks for the information, one never stops learning new things.